# How to enable virtual host for local development

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to access a folder in my ubuntu machine from another port.If I type localhost:81 in browser it should show me a content from a folder. And display a welome message on browser.

Right now I have created a folder inside html folder which simply shows a welcome message. If I visit localhost/site it is showing me the expected result correctly. So I made some changes.

I created a file inside

> /etc/apache2/sites-available

named `site.conf` with the following content in it.

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
<Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And made

```
sudo a2ensite site.conf                                
Enabling site site.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
service apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server apache2                                                                                                                  *
```

Then I visitted `http://localhost:81/` It is throwing me an error `This site can’t be reached` Where as `http://localhost/site/` Is showing me the welcome message correctly. Where am I going wrong how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Apache should be listening port 81 right not the port 80 as of above config file.Just try `<VirtualHost *:81>`

Comment: @Nuwan My typo I have changed the code

Comment: try adding the line `Listen 81` just before `<VirtualHost *:81>`

Comment: I have added and reloaded apache but nothing happens :(

Comment: How can i track what is happening atleast?

Comment: oops...You are not enabled your virtualhost file.Just run `sudo a2ensite *`.And then restart apache

Comment: @Nuwan I have done that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184134/discussion-between-nuwan-and-arun-vm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` with

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
```

If your apache process seems hanged.then Kill all your apache processes

```
ps -aux|grep
kill -9 PISs
```

Then start the apache server

```
sudo service apache2 start
```